# XML/Android: Little black line under RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, xml

I have a RecyclerView and there are items in it. Under every item there is a little black line from left to right, how can I get rid off it?[image]

Comment: Can you screen grab what the issue is? and the code you are using to set the RecyclerView.  It's more than likely that your XML for your viewHolder needs to be adjusted.

Comment: it look like you are using cardview for recyclerview item. you can remove the shadow by `card_view:cardElevation="0dp"`

Comment: Post the xml code....for list_view row layout.

Comment: please post your viewholder xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CardView` as item view so the line is the shadow of that, remove or change the `CardView` with other container(`LinearLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`) or set `card_view:cardElevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove card view shadow Like this.

`<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"/>`